# What "actions" did Toneri Otsutsuki perform on Boruto

Tags: naruto, boruto

In Boruto Episode 53, After Urashiki finally found Toneri, they both had a brief discussion about how the Main Branch of the Otsutsuki Clan had been monitoring everything that happened for the past thousand years.

Right before their battle, Urashiki  told Toneri: ***"You may think you made the first move by doing something to that womans son, but that was very hastily prepared"*** (he meant Boruto, who is the Son of the Byakugan Princess).

**What exactly did Toneri do to Boruto?** I'm guessing it has to do with his Jogan.

> What is the connection between Boruto and Toneri? because I also remember Boruto's Jogan was activated immidiately after Toneri appeared in his dream.